How to remove the comma before pages in latex citation when the article does not possess a volume number?
I'm trying to cite this research paper. However, it seems that this research paper does not possess a volume number. Therefore, when I try to cite this paper in my paper using latex, there is an annoying comma before the pages.

How can I eliminate this comma? The ideal effect will be the following which I found in one published research paper:


Please confirm that you use biblatex. If so, is there any particular style you employ?

@narip Please add a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)

Technically, the 2300218 number is not a page number, but an electronic identifier (the eid field). Despite the journal's own citation guidelines categorising this number as a page number, this classification is completely wrong.
You may customise the \bibeidpunct punctuation command for delimitation.
\renewcommand*{\bibeidpunct}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{volume}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{number}}}%
        {\space}%
        {\addcomma\space}}

However, I think it would be better to customise the volume+number+eid macro. So, instead of change the \bibeidpunct command, change that macro:
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \iffieldundef{volume}%
        {}%
        {\setunit*{\adddot}}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{volume}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{number}}}%
        {\setunit{\addspace}}%
        {\bibeidpunct}%
    \printfield{eid}}


Of course, I'm assuming you're using the biblatex package. I posted a response without waiting for confirmation, because it's important to establish that the 2300218 number doesn't correspond to the page number, but rather to the EID.
